# Number of years between two dates

Tags: datetime, vb6

I am trying to do a fairly trivial task however my experience is in .net not in vb6. Given two strings (say `"10/17/94"` and `"10/17/95"` for this example) I want to return a string expression

X years

```
//Date_Due and Date_Time_Performed are strings in the mm/dd/yy format
Duration = (Year(CDate(Date_Due)) - Year(CDate(Date_Time_Performed))) & " years"
```

but that gives me a `runtime error '13' Type Mismatch`.

Any suggestions?

EDIT:
None of the answers have adressed this yet. The result of the conversion must be added on to the " years" string. I need the string representation not the int.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using `datediff`

```
Duration = CStr(DateDiff("yyyy", CDate(Date_Due), CDate(Date_Time_Performed))) & " years"
```

Comment: Duration = DateDiff("yyyy", CDate(Date_Due), CDate(Date_Time_Performed)) & " years" gives a type mismatch How do I cast the result of dateDiff in to a string?

Comment: @Scott - You can wrap the DateDiff call in CStr()

Answer (score 0):

```
Duration = DateDiff("yyyy", d1, d2)
```

However, to avoid locale-based issues, you better manually convert your strings to dates first:

```
d1 = DateSerial(1900 + cint(right$(literal,2)), cint(left$(literal,2)), cint(mid$(literal,4,2)))
```

That is provided your dates are always mm/dd/yy. If you are using locale-dependant date formats, just use the `CDate` function.

Comment: DateDiff returns a int not a string, how do I cast the result in to a string?

Answer (score 0):

```
Duration = CStr(DateDiff("yyyy", Date_Time_Performed, Date_Due))
```

The string "yyyy" resturns the interval in years.  You can also return the interval in other units.

- *yyyy* - Year
- *q* - Quarter
- *m* - Month
- *d* - Day
- *ww* - Week
- *h* - Hour
- *n* - Minute
- *s* - Second

Comment: DateDiff returns a int not a string, how do I cast the result in to a string?